# How to group the values in json array to be displayed in a listview?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-listview

How to group the values in json array to be displayed in a listview?
this is example of arrayjson :`

```
"caleg": [
            {
                "id": "jk",
                "tahun": 2014,
                "nama": "Jusuf Kalla",
                "role": "cawapres",
                "id_running_mate": "jw",
                "jenis_kelamin": "L",
                "agama": "Islam",
                "tempat_lahir": "Watampone, Sulawesi Selatan",
                "tanggal_lahir": "1942-05-15",
                "status_perkawinan": "Kawin",
                "nama_pasangan": "Hj. Mufidah Yusuf",
                "jumlah_anak": 5,
                "kelurahan_tinggal": "",
                "kecamatan_tinggal": "",
                "kab_kota_tinggal": "Jakarta Selatan",
                "provinsi_tinggal": "DKI Jakarta"}]"
```

I want to group in custom listview like this:
[image: listview in detail of biograph]

how to do this?
because when I use hashmap and arrraylist, it's not work..

Answer (score 0):

With [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) use JsonNode

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

for(JsonNode node: rootNode.getElements()) {
    //add to your listview with e.g. node.getTextValue() 
}
```

get the field names with

```
rootNode.getFieldNames()
```

For reading your root array check out this post

[Jackson how to transform JsonNode to ArrayNode without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788213/jackson-how-to-transform-jsonnode-to-arraynode-without-casting)

source:

- http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/