# How to convert a String into object and retrieve the value using Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, parsing, jackson

I have a Json request which is in the form of a String :-

```
 {
      "insertDataRequest": [
          {
              "id": "98",
              "name": "Mercer Island",
              "age": "12",
              "designation": "SSE"
          }
      ]
  }
```

Now , I need to convert this String format into Java Object and retrieve it's value using Jackson ...

So far I did the following :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json= "{\"insertDataRequest\":{\"id\":98, \"name\":\"Mercer Island\",\"age\":12,\"designation\":\"SEE\"}}";
    JsonNode root2 = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    JsonNode rootnode = root2.get("insertDataRequest");

    if (rootnode != null && rootnode.has("id")) {
        int id = rootnode.get("id").intValue();
        System.out.println(id);
    }     
    if (rootnode != null && rootnode.has("name")) {
        String name = rootnode.get("name").toString().replace("\"", "");
        System.out.println(name);
    }   

    if (rootnode != null && rootnode.has("age")) {
        int age = rootnode.get("age").intValue();
        System.out.println(age);
    }

    if (rootnode != null && rootnode.has("designation")) {
        String designation = rootnode.get("designation").toString().replace("\"", "");
        System.out.println(designation);
    }    
}
```

Now .. I am not getting any value when I run the code ....How can I convert this String and retrieve the value .. Is I am missing something ??? Please help ....

Comment: Use your debugger, and inspect the variables. Note that the insertDataRequest attributes is an **array** of one object. Not an object.

Comment: if I remove '[' from the request I am able to get the values .. But I require '[' ...Since the values can repeat .. How can I get it using '[' ...

Comment: Read the javadoc of JsonNode. Find the method which allows getting the element at index 0. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Comment: I have searched all over the net .. but didn't find any suitable way to iterate the request in the given format .. Please help me in getting a way to iterate and fetch the value

Comment: That's your error. You shouldn't search all over the net. You should read the javadoc of JsonNode to understand how you can use it, and access the element at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ObjectMapper you could probably use a bean to map your JSON directly to your Java object without doing it by yourself.

For your code, and based on the comment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json= "{\"insertDataRequest\":{\"id\":98, \"name\":\"Mercer Island\",\"age\":12,\"designation\":\"SEE\"}}";
    JsonNode root2 = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    for (JsonNode rootnode : root2.get("insertDataRequest")) {
      if (rootnode.has("id")) {
          int id = rootnode.get("id").intValue();
          System.out.println(id);
      }     
      if (rootnode.has("name")) {
          String name = rootnode.get("name").toString().replace("\"", "");
          System.out.println(name);
      }   

      if (rootnode.has("age")) {
          int age = rootnode.get("age").intValue();
          System.out.println(age);
      }

      if (rootnode.has("designation")) {
          String designation = rootnode.get("designation").toString().replace("\"", "");
          System.out.println(designation);
      }    
    }
}
```

[JSONNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) implements `Iterable`.

Comment: One slight correction .. It's working as JsonNode rootnode : root2.get("insertDataRequest") instead of JsonNode rootnode = root2.get("insertDataRequest") ... need to remove '=' with ':' and it's working fine .. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the `ObjectMapper` to read your JSON as an array of POJOs and pick up the first array element without going through the node hierarchy. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonWrapped {
    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "      \"insertDataRequest\": [\n" +
            "          {\n" +
            "              \"id\": \"98\",\n" +
            "              \"name\": \"Mercer Island\",\n" +
            "              \"age\": \"12\",\n" +
            "              \"designation\": \"SSE\"\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "  }";

    public static class Bean {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public String designation;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", age=" + age +
                    ", designation='" + designation + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Bean[] value = mapper.reader(Bean[].class)
                .withRootName("insertDataRequest")
                .readValue(JSON);
        System.out.println(value[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bean{id=98, name='Mercer Island', age=12, designation='SSE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer using the same object type JsonNode. The node itself can be an array:

[Jackson how to transform JsonNode to ArrayNode without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788213/jackson-how-to-transform-jsonnode-to-arraynode-without-casting)

Answer (score 0):

So, the working solution is as NoDataFound suggested :-

```
JsonNode root2 = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    for (JsonNode rootnode : root2.get("insertDataRequest")) {
      if (rootnode.has("id")) {
          int id = rootnode.get("id").intValue();
          System.out.println(id);
      }
```