# EOF Exception using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to parse an external file which contains json. The json in the file takes this form:

```json
{
    "timestamp": MY_TIMESTAMP,
    "serial": "MY_SERIAL",
    "data": [{
        MY_DATA
    }, {
        MY_DATA
    }]
}
```

The code I am trying to use to access this is as follows:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(dataFileLocation);
JsonNode data = root.get("data");
ArrayList<AriaInactiveExchange> exchangeList = mapper.readValue(data.toString(), new TypeReference<List<AriaInactiveExchange>>(){});
```

I have validated the location of the dataFile and the data in it. I'm positive that i'm doing something wrong and that this may not even be the right approach. But the idea is clear that I need to get to "data" and map that to an Array.

When this code is run the following line instantly throws an EOF exception:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(dataFileLocation);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16793133/3858121

Comment: You didn't show the data that this fails on.  Perhaps it is simply malformed.